# cufftSetStream causes garbage output. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: cuda, cufft

According to the docs, the [`cufftSetStream()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/#function-cufftsetstream) function

> Associates a CUDA stream with a cuFFT plan. All kernel launches made during plan execution are now done through the associated stream [...until...]  the stream is changed with another call to cufftSetStream().

Unfortunately, the results are turned into garbage.  Here is an example that demonstrates this by performing a bunch of transforms two ways: once with each stream having its own dedicated plan, and once with a single plan being reused as the documentation above indicates.  The former behaves as expected, the reused/cufftSetStream approach has errors in most of the transforms.  This was observed on the two cards I've tried (GTX 750 ti, Titan X) on CentOS 7 linux with
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.0, V7.0.27; and release 7.5, V7.5.17.

*EDIT* :see the "FIX" comments below for one way to fix things.

```
#include <cufft.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

#define ck(cmd) if ( cmd) { std::cerr << "error at line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;exit(1);}


__global__
void fill_input(cufftComplex * buf, int batch,int nbins,int stride,int seed)
{
    for (int i = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y; i< batch;i += gridDim.y*blockDim.y)
        for (int j = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; j< nbins;j += gridDim.x*blockDim.x)
            buf[i*stride + j] = make_cuFloatComplex( (i+seed)%101 - 50,(j+seed)%41-20);
}

__global__
void check_output(const float * buf1,const float * buf2,int batch, int nfft, int stride, int * errors)
{
    for (int i = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y; i< batch;i += gridDim.y*blockDim.y) {
        for (int j = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; j< nfft;j += gridDim.x*blockDim.x) {
            float e=buf1[i*stride+j] - buf2[i*stride+j];
            if (e*e > 1) // gross error
                atomicAdd(errors,1);
        }
    }
}

void demo(bool reuse_plan)
{
    if (reuse_plan)
        std::cout << "Reusing the same fft plan with multiple stream via cufftSetStream ... ";
    else
        std::cout << "Giving each stream its own dedicated fft plan ... ";
    int nfft = 1024;
    int batch = 1024;
    int nstreams = 8;
    int nbins = nfft/2+1;
    int nit=100;
    size_t inpitch,outpitch;

    std::vector<cufftComplex*> inbufs(nstreams);
    std::vector<float*> outbufs(nstreams);
    std::vector<float*> checkbufs(nstreams);
    std::vector<cudaStream_t> streams(nstreams);
    std::vector<cufftHandle> plans(nstreams);
    for (int i=0;i<nstreams;++i) {
        ck( cudaStreamCreate(&streams[i]));
        ck( cudaMallocPitch((void**)&inbufs[i],&inpitch,nbins*sizeof(cufftComplex),batch) );
        ck( cudaMallocPitch((void**)&outbufs[i],&outpitch,nfft*sizeof(float),batch));
        ck( cudaMallocPitch((void**)&checkbufs[i],&outpitch,nfft*sizeof(float),batch) );
        if (i==0 || reuse_plan==false)
            ck ( cufftPlanMany(&plans[i],1,&nfft,&nbins,1,inpitch/sizeof(cufftComplex),&nfft,1,outpitch/sizeof(float),CUFFT_C2R,batch) );
    }

    // fill the input buffers and FFT them to get a baseline for comparison
    for (int i=0;i<nstreams;++i) {
        fill_input<<<20,dim3(32,32)>>>(inbufs[i],batch,nbins,inpitch/sizeof(cufftComplex),i);
        ck (cudaGetLastError());
        if (reuse_plan) {
            ck (cufftExecC2R(plans[0],inbufs[i],checkbufs[i]));
        }else{
            ck (cufftExecC2R(plans[i],inbufs[i],checkbufs[i]));
            ck( cufftSetStream(plans[i],streams[i]) ); // only need to set the stream once
        }
        ck( cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    }
    // allocate a buffer for the error count
    int * errors;
    cudaMallocHost((void**)&errors,sizeof(int)*nit);
    memset(errors,0,sizeof(int)*nit);

    /* FIX: an event can protect the plan internal buffers 
    by serializing access to the plan
    cudaEvent_t ev;
    cudaEventCreateWithFlags(&ev,cudaEventDisableTiming);
    */

    // perform the FFTs and check the outputs on streams
    for (int it=0;it<nit;++it) {
        int k = it % nstreams;
        ck( cudaStreamSynchronize(streams[k]) ); // make sure any prior kernels have completed
        if (reuse_plan) {
            // FIX: ck(cudaStreamWaitEvent(streams[k],ev,0 ) );
            ck(cufftSetStream(plans[0],streams[k]));
            ck(cufftExecC2R(plans[0],inbufs[k],outbufs[k]));
            // FIX: ck(cudaEventRecord(ev,streams[k] ) );
        }else{
            ck(cufftExecC2R(plans[k],inbufs[k],outbufs[k]));
        }
        check_output<<<100,dim3(32,32),0,streams[k]>>>(outbufs[k],checkbufs[k],batch,nfft,outpitch/sizeof(float),&errors[it]);
        ck (cudaGetLastError());
    }
    ck(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    // report number of errors
    int errcount=0;
    for (int it=0;it<nit;++it)
        if (errors[it])
            ++errcount;
    std::cout << errcount << " of " << nit << " transforms had errors\n";

    for (int i=0;i<nstreams;++i) {
        cudaFree(inbufs[i]);
        cudaFree(outbufs[i]);
        cudaStreamDestroy(streams[i]);
        if (i==0 || reuse_plan==false)
            cufftDestroy(plans[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
    demo(false);
    demo(true);
    return 0;
}
```

Typical output

> Giving each stream its own dedicated fft plan ... 0 of 100 transforms  had errors
>   Reusing the same fft plan with multiple stream via cufftSetStream ... 87 of 100 transforms had errors

Comment: When I compile and run the code you posted using CUDA 7.0 on a very modest mobile GPU, I get 0 errors for both cases.

Comment: @talonmies, thanks for the data point.  I just tried it with cuda 7.0 -- also failed  (see edits) Perhaps the "modesty" of your card is keeping it from failing (i.e. fewer resources == less race conditions). What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 10 with a compute 2.1 device

Comment: @RobertCrovella  I think your theory about the SetStream being applied retroactively makes sense.  Perhaps some  kernels are being launched *after* the exec function returns (with wrong stream).  While I agree that the documentation is a bit vague in its promise, the "until [] another call to cufftSetStream", suggests what I'm trying to do should be supported.

Comment: Also.  You don't need the cudaDeviceSynchronize sledgehammer to make it behave.  Surrounding the SetStream+Exec with { cudaStreamWaitEvent(streams[k],event,0 ) and cudaEventRecord(event,streams[k] ) } also fixes it.  This would serialize the execution of the fft plan kernels, but not previous&subsequent kernels.

Comment: Yes, the `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` was just a test to attempt to indicate whether there may be a connection to or impact on previously issued work.  I wasn't suggesting it as a fix.  I'm continuing to investigate as time permits and will report back if/when I have any further updates.

Comment: @MarkBorgerding I don't think it is some kernels being launched after you change the stream (realistically this can only happen if cuFFT has it's own thread). I'd assume cuFFT plans usually have some scratch space associated with them. If you are trying to use the same plan with two streams simultaneously, both of them are going to read and write from the same scratch space resulting in incorrect values.

Comment: @PavanYalamanchili, your analysis makes sense.  Assuming that is correct (and assuming I don't want to create one plan per stream), is event record/streamwait  the best method to prevent parallel execution of the same plan?

Comment: @MarkBorgerding you could do that, but then you are not gaining anything over using a single stream (unless you are doing other things on various streams not shown in this example).

Comment: @PavanYalamanchili, In the real-world application I'm developing, there is considerable work done in other kernels besides the FFTs, so serializing the FFT plan execution does not kill the reason for multiple streams.  With sufficient batch size, the FFT does a pretty good job of occupying the whole device anyway.  Serializing fft exec may be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to reuse plans the way you want you need to manage cuFFT work area manually.

Each plan has a space for intermediate calculation results. If you want to use plan handle **at the same time** for two or more different plan executions you need to provide temporary buffer for each concurrent cufftExec* call.

You can do this by using cufftSetWorkArea - please have a look at section 3.7 in cuFFT documentation. Section 2.2 also would help to understand how it works.

Here's a worked example showing the changes to your code for this:

```
$ cat t1241.cu
#include <cufft.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

#define ck(cmd) if ( cmd) { std::cerr << "error at line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;exit(1);}


__global__
void fill_input(cufftComplex * buf, int batch,int nbins,int stride,int seed)
{
    for (int i = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y; i< batch;i += gridDim.y*blockDim.y)
        for (int j = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; j< nbins;j += gridDim.x*blockDim.x)
            buf[i*stride + j] = make_cuFloatComplex( (i+seed)%101 - 50,(j+seed)%41-20);
}

__global__
void check_output(const float * buf1,const float * buf2,int batch, int nfft, int stride, int * errors)
{
    for (int i = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y; i< batch;i += gridDim.y*blockDim.y) {
        for (int j = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; j< nfft;j += gridDim.x*blockDim.x) {
            float e=buf1[i*stride+j] - buf2[i*stride+j];
            if (e*e > 1) // gross error
                atomicAdd(errors,1);
        }
    }
}

void demo(bool reuse_plan)
{
    if (reuse_plan)
        std::cout << "Reusing the same fft plan with multiple stream via cufftSetStream ... ";
    else
        std::cout << "Giving each stream its own dedicated fft plan ... ";
    int nfft = 1024;
    int batch = 1024;
    int nstreams = 8;
    int nbins = nfft/2+1;
    int nit=100;
    size_t inpitch,outpitch;

    std::vector<cufftComplex*> inbufs(nstreams);
    std::vector<float*> outbufs(nstreams);
    std::vector<float*> checkbufs(nstreams);
    std::vector<cudaStream_t> streams(nstreams);
    std::vector<cufftHandle> plans(nstreams);
    // if plan reuse, set up independent work areas
    std::vector<char *> wk_areas(nstreams);
    for (int i=0;i<nstreams;++i) {
        ck( cudaStreamCreate(&streams[i]));
        ck( cudaMallocPitch((void**)&inbufs[i],&inpitch,nbins*sizeof(cufftComplex),batch) );
        ck( cudaMallocPitch((void**)&outbufs[i],&outpitch,nfft*sizeof(float),batch));
        ck( cudaMallocPitch((void**)&checkbufs[i],&outpitch,nfft*sizeof(float),batch) );
        if (i==0 || reuse_plan==false)
            ck ( cufftPlanMany(&plans[i],1,&nfft,&nbins,1,inpitch/sizeof(cufftComplex),&nfft,1,outpitch/sizeof(float),CUFFT_C2R,batch) );
    }
    if (reuse_plan){
      size_t ws;
      ck(cufftGetSize(plans[0], &ws));
      for (int i = 0; i < nstreams; i++)
        ck(cudaMalloc(&(wk_areas[i]), ws));
      ck(cufftSetAutoAllocation(plans[0], 0));
      ck(cufftSetWorkArea(plans[0], wk_areas[0]));
      }
    // fill the input buffers and FFT them to get a baseline for comparison
    for (int i=0;i<nstreams;++i) {
        fill_input<<<20,dim3(32,32)>>>(inbufs[i],batch,nbins,inpitch/sizeof(cufftComplex),i);
        ck (cudaGetLastError());
        if (reuse_plan) {
            ck (cufftExecC2R(plans[0],inbufs[i],checkbufs[i]));
        }else{
            ck (cufftExecC2R(plans[i],inbufs[i],checkbufs[i]));
            ck( cufftSetStream(plans[i],streams[i]) ); // only need to set the stream once
        }
        ck( cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    }
    // allocate a buffer for the error count
    int * errors;
    cudaMallocHost((void**)&errors,sizeof(int)*nit);
    memset(errors,0,sizeof(int)*nit);

    // perform the FFTs and check the outputs on streams
    for (int it=0;it<nit;++it) {
        int k = it % nstreams;
        ck( cudaStreamSynchronize(streams[k]) ); // make sure any prior kernels have completed
        if (reuse_plan) {
            ck(cufftSetStream(plans[0],streams[k]));
            ck(cufftSetWorkArea(plans[0], wk_areas[k])); // update work area pointer in plan
            ck(cufftExecC2R(plans[0],inbufs[k],outbufs[k]));
        }else{
            ck(cufftExecC2R(plans[k],inbufs[k],outbufs[k]));
        }
        check_output<<<100,dim3(32,32),0,streams[k]>>>(outbufs[k],checkbufs[k],batch,nfft,outpitch/sizeof(float),&errors[it]);
        ck (cudaGetLastError());
    }
    ck(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    // report number of errors
    int errcount=0;
    for (int it=0;it<nit;++it)
        if (errors[it])
            ++errcount;
    std::cout << errcount << " of " << nit << " transforms had errors\n";

    for (int i=0;i<nstreams;++i) {
        cudaFree(inbufs[i]);
        cudaFree(outbufs[i]);
        cudaFree(wk_areas[i]);
        cudaStreamDestroy(streams[i]);
        if (i==0 || reuse_plan==false)
            cufftDestroy(plans[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
    demo(false);
    demo(true);
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1241 t1241.cu -lcufft
$ ./t1241
Giving each stream its own dedicated fft plan ... 0 of 100 transforms had errors
Reusing the same fft plan with multiple stream via cufftSetStream ... 0 of 100 transforms had errors
$
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it gets to the heart of the problem and it provides _a_ way to fix it .  The problem is that cufft plans have internal work buffers unsafe for use in parallel streams.  In my opinion, synchronizing access with an event is a better solution. First of all, a good-sized cufft plan execution keeps the device pretty busy.  So serial plan execution is not that costly by itself.  The extra synchronization cost appears negligible.  This retains the single-plan memory footprint without garbage output.  See the "FIX" comments in my updated code.

Comment: Is extra memory footprint much burden for you?

Comment: Yes. There could be hundreds of "channels" in my application, each needing a possibly different FFT size.  I'd rather not multiply that memory requirement by the number of streams.

Comment: If we are not using streams, is it safe to use a work area with the maximum size for all cufftExec?

Comment: You mean reuse single work area for different plans? Yes, that would work.